# pass password to CVS login from command line argument

Tags: shell, version-control, sh, cvs

my requirement is to pass password via command line argument for CVS login.

I have created a shell script file: `test.sh` have code like:

```
#for cvs login and putting password
cvs -q -d :pserver:username@190.190.190.190:2401/root/cvsrepo login -p
echo "hello"
```

[image: Terminal outpuy]

**When I am running it. It is still asking for password. I want to make it automatic. Please suggest me how can I do so?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have to install expect for this.

Install expect:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install expect

My `test.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn cvs -q -d :pserver:username@190.190.190.190:2401/root/cvsrepo login
expect 
send -- "hello\r"
expect eof
```